# how to specify the platform (android or ios) test with nunit console

Tags: ios, xamarin, jenkins, nunit, xamarin.uitest

I have a xamarin ui test multiplateform project, I would like to know if I launch my test via the console it is possible to launch only ios or android tests. For if it launches the two ...
my current command line is :

```
mono /Users/Shared/opt/NUnit/nunit3-console.exe /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/build_project/UITest/bin/Debug/UITest.dll
```

Thank's for your help

Comment: I would like to be able to choose the launch platform of the testes (iOS or Android)

Answer (score 1):

I find the solution, I need to add `--test="UITest.Tests(my_platform)"` to select either iOS or Android!