# Run Xamarin.UI tests from command line for a specific platform

Tags: xamarin, .net-core, nunit, nunit-console, xamarin.uitest

I have a `Xamarin.UITest` project than contains UI tests for both Android and iOS. All tests inherit from a base class that looks like:

```cs
[TestFixture(Platform.Android)]
[TestFixture(Platform.iOS)]
public abstract class UITestBase
{
    private readonly Platform _platform;
    protected IApp App { get; private set; }

    protected UITestBase(Platform platform)
    {
        _platform = platform;
    }

    [SetUp]
    protected virtual async Task BeforeEachTest()
    {
        App = AppInitializer.StartApp(_platform);
        await Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

So, all tests will run for both Android and iOS. Now, in an IDE such as Visual Studio or Rider, it easily lets me run tests only for a specific platform - while developing, I often only want to run tests for Android, for example.

How can I run tests only for a specific platform from the command line?

`dotnet test` will run them for both platforms, and I can't see a way to filter using NUnit's `TestFixture` attribute.

While I'd prefer a method using `dotnet test`, it would also be OK to use the NUnit console runner, `nunit3-console.exe`, but again I can't figure out how to filter using `TestFixture` arguments.

Comment: You can try the answer in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52699329/how-to-specify-the-platform-android-or-ios-test-with-nunit-console).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT that does at least work for individual tests, but I can't find a way to make it run all tests (tried wildcards): `nunit3-console.exe MyAssembly.dll --test="My.Fully.Qualified.Test.Class(Android)"`

Comment: Category parameter worked perfectly but I couldn't make text fixture parameter work. nunit3-console.exe Xamarin.UITest.dll --where=cat==High

Comment: Does `dotnet test` really work? It only restores my ui test project but doesn't run any tests

Comment: @pschlz yes, or at least "it works on my machine" :P

Comment: @Cocowalla It's now working on my machine. The trick was not to use Xamarin.UITest Cross-Platform template but to create a NUnut Test Project (.NET Core), copy the relevant files from UI Test project and set the TargetFramework in .csproj file to `net472`

Answer (score 1):

With dotnet-test (see [run selective unit tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/selective-unit-tests?pivots=mstest))

```
dotnet test Tests.dll--filter iOS

dotnet test Tests.dll--filter Android
```

Or use nunit3-console-runner with [Test Selection Language](https://docs.nunit.org/articles/nunit/running-tests/Test-Selection-Language.html) :

```
nunit3-console.exe Tests.dll --where "test =~ iOS"

nunit3-console.exe Tests.dll --where "test =~ Android"
```